# Aggregate rows ahead only where one value in the row ahead is less than another

Tags: sql, sql-server, time-series, sql-server-2016, window-functions

I am in a situation where I have two counts for every machine, `p` and `r`.

`p` *should* always be greater than or equal to `r`, but due to technical lags and short aggregation periods this is not always the case, with the `r` count often - but not always - showing data from a previous period.  Because the length of the lag is not constant, there is no way to know exactly which period the `r` value belongs to.  Consequently I cannot simply move all the `r` counts uniformly backwards in time as this may create other disparities where previously there was none.

This situation cannot be changed and I have to deal with the data as is.

In the example below, you can see that the the `p` counts 'pause' for a brief period on machine `1` and slow significantly on machine `2`, but the `r` count continues to return values greater than `p` for a brief time before also 'pausing':

```
-- Dummy data
declare @t table(d date,m int,p int,r int);
insert into @t values(getdate()-9,1,100,10),(getdate()-8,1,90 ,10),(getdate()-7,1,70 ,10),(getdate()-6,1,70 ,10),(getdate()-5,1,80 ,10),(getdate()-4,1,50 ,10),(getdate()-3,1,10 ,10),(getdate()-2,1,0  ,10),(getdate()-1,1,0  ,10),(getdate()+0,1,0  ,10),(getdate()+1,1,0  ,0),(getdate()+2,1,0  ,0),(getdate()+3,1,40 ,0),(getdate()+4,1,50 ,0),(getdate()+5,1,80 ,10),(getdate()-9,2,1100,100),(getdate()-8,2,190 ,100),(getdate()-7,2,170 ,100),(getdate()-6,2,170 ,100),(getdate()-5,2,180 ,100),(getdate()-4,2,150 ,100),(getdate()-3,2,110 ,100),(getdate()-2,2,10  ,100),(getdate()-1,2,10  ,100),(getdate()+0,2,10  ,100),(getdate()+1,2,10  ,0),(getdate()+2,2,10  ,0),(getdate()+3,2,140 ,0),(getdate()+4,2,150 ,0),(getdate()+5,2,180 ,100);
select * from @t order by m,d;

-- Output
+------------+---+------+-----+
|     d      | m |  p   |  r  |
+------------+---+------+-----+
| 2020-05-27 | 1 |  100 |  10 |
| 2020-05-28 | 1 |   90 |  10 |
| 2020-05-29 | 1 |   70 |  10 |
| 2020-05-30 | 1 |   70 |  10 |
| 2020-05-31 | 1 |   80 |  10 |
| 2020-06-01 | 1 |   50 |  10 |
| 2020-06-02 | 1 |   10 |  10 |
| 2020-06-03 | 1 |    0 |  10 |
| 2020-06-04 | 1 |    0 |  10 |
| 2020-06-05 | 1 |    0 |  10 |
| 2020-06-06 | 1 |    0 |   0 |
| 2020-06-07 | 1 |    0 |   0 |
| 2020-06-08 | 1 |   40 |   0 |
| 2020-06-09 | 1 |   50 |   0 |
| 2020-06-10 | 1 |   80 |  10 |
| 2020-05-27 | 2 | 1100 | 100 |
| 2020-05-28 | 2 |  190 | 100 |
| 2020-05-29 | 2 |  170 | 100 |
| 2020-05-30 | 2 |  170 | 100 |
| 2020-05-31 | 2 |  180 | 100 |
| 2020-06-01 | 2 |  150 | 100 |
| 2020-06-02 | 2 |  110 | 100 |
| 2020-06-03 | 2 |   10 | 100 |
| 2020-06-04 | 2 |   10 | 100 |
| 2020-06-05 | 2 |   10 | 100 |
| 2020-06-06 | 2 |   10 |   0 |
| 2020-06-07 | 2 |   10 |   0 |
| 2020-06-08 | 2 |  140 |   0 |
| 2020-06-09 | 2 |  150 |   0 |
| 2020-06-10 | 2 |  180 | 100 |
+------------+---+------+-----+
```

I need to be able to sensibly adjust those `r` counts backwards in time some degree, so that they are added to prior rows in a way that keeps each `p` number greater than or equal to the corresponding `r` value.

In the above example for `m = 1`, the output could look something like ***any*** of the following `r` counts; I don't care about the spread of the adjustment, only that `p` `>=` `r` for every row and adjustments only ever travel backwards in time:

```
+------------+---+------+------+------+------+
|     d      | m |  p   |  r1  |  r2  |  r3  |
+------------+---+------+------+------+------+
| 2020-05-27 | 1 |  100 |   10 |   10 |   10 |
| 2020-05-28 | 1 |   90 |   10 |   10 |   10 |
| 2020-05-29 | 1 |   70 |   10 |   15 |   10 |
| 2020-05-30 | 1 |   70 |   20 |   20 |   10 |) Note how the original 30 r counts
| 2020-05-31 | 1 |   80 |   20 |   20 |   10 |} that didn't follow the rule
| 2020-06-01 | 1 |   50 |   20 |   15 |   40 |) have been moved back in time
| 2020-06-02 | 1 |   10 |   10 |   10 |   10 |
| 2020-06-03 | 1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 2020-06-04 | 1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 2020-06-05 | 1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 2020-06-06 | 1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 2020-06-07 | 1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 2020-06-08 | 1 |   40 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 2020-06-09 | 1 |   50 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 2020-06-10 | 1 |   80 |   10 |   10 |   10 |
+------------+---+------+------+------+------+
```

I have tried solvng this with window functions and `rows between` etc but I can't work out how to identify the `r` values that need to be re-assigned to previous periods, as well as also identifying which `p` value to assign them to.  If I make any progress I will add it in below, but all help is much appreciated.

---

## Attempt 1

The closest I have managed is the following which works for the above, but fails when you change the `p = 50` value to something less than `40` and also adjusts both forwards and backwards in time, when I only want backwards:

```
with t as(
select row_number() over (partition by m order by d) as rn
      ,(row_number() over (partition by m order by d)-1) / 5 as gn
      ,*
from @t
where m = 1
)
select *
      ,case when p > r
            then r + (sum(case when p < r then r else 0 end) over (partition by gn) / sum(case when p > r then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by gn))
            else case when p = r
                      then r
                      else 0
                      end
            end as r_adj
from t;
```

---

## Attempt 2

This is closer, but is still adjusting forwards in time as well as backwards:

```
with t as(
select row_number() over (partition by m order by d) as rn
      ,(row_number() over (partition by m order by d)-1) / 10 as gn
      ,(row_number() over (partition by m order by d)+4) / 10 as gn2
      ,*
from @t
where m = 1
)
,r1 as(
select *
      ,case when p > r
            then r + (sum(case when p < r then r - p else 0 end) over (partition by gn) / sum(case when p > r then 1. else 0. end) over (partition by gn))
            else case when p = r
                      then r
                      else 0
                      end
            end as r_adj
from t
)
select d
      ,m
      ,p
      ,r
      ,case when p > r_adj
            then r_adj + (sum(case when p < r_adj then r_adj - p else 0 end) over (partition by gn2) / sum(case when p > r_adj then 1. else 0. end) over (partition by gn2))
            else case when p = r_adj
                      then r_adj
                      else r_adj - (r_adj - p)
                      end
            end as r_new
from r1
order by rn
;
```

Comment: can you put up your SQL Code?

Comment: the concern I have is how you generate the r field from the source.

Comment: The `r` field *is* the source.  As I say it is arrives as you see it above and needs to be adjusted accordingly to fit the `p >= r` rule.

Comment: if what you are showing me is the source table, then you have to  backtrack from there.  You need to find out how to relate r to a form of "primary key" so you can determine which records are bad, and how many rows you are needing to offset.  The objective is to "re-align" r with the proper field.  if it was me, I would be asking the people who populate that table to quantify it.

Comment: As I said in the OP: *This situation cannot be changed and I have to deal with the data as is.*  Not all data in the world comes from another database.  In this instance, the data comes directly from sensors attached to real world machines and arrives as is.  There is no 'primary key' to backtrack to nor can I change the output of the sensors.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  You have *three* `r` values in your result set.  Which do you want?

Comment: Any.  They all follow the rule of `p >= r`.  I have written it that way to show that the spread of the adjusted `r` values is not important, so long as it is less than the `p`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this working with what should be an acceptable very small margin of error using the script below.

It works by checking the row ahead to see if there is an excess `r` and if so adds it to the current row.  The same process is then run on the output of this, effectively moving any excesses up to two rows backwards in time.  This covers the majority of cases in the real world data.

Finally, it then checks for any excesses left over and finds the timestamp of the most recent row with a `p` value over a certain threshold to move the excess into.  If there are no rows with `p > r` beforehand (e.g. First data periods received have this issue right out the gate), it fetches the nearest one in the future.

```
with t as(
select *
      ,case when lead(p - r) over (partition by m order by d) < 0
            then case when p - r < 0
                        then p
                        else r
                        end
                 + abs(lead(p - r,1,0) over (partition by m order by d))
            else case when p - r >= 0
                        then r
                        else r  + (p - r)
                        end
            end
as r1
from @t
)
,b2 as(
select *
      ,case when lead(p - r1) over (partition by m order by d) < 0
            then case when p - r1 < 0
                        then p
                        else r1
                        end
                 + abs(lead(p - r1,1,0) over (partition by m order by d))
            else case when p - r1 >= 0
                        then r1
                        else r1 + (p - r1)
                        end
            end
        as r2
from t
)
,d as(
select *
      ,case when p - r2 < 0
            then case when max(case when p - r2 > 30 then d else '19000101' end) over (partition by m order by d rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) = '19000101'
                        then min(case when p - r2 > 30 then d else '29990101' end) over (partition by m order by d rows between 1 following and unbounded following)
                        else max(case when p - r2 > 30 then d else '19000101' end) over (partition by m order by d rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
                        end
            else null
            end as drep
from b2
)
,dover as
(
select drep
      ,m
      ,sum(p) as p
      ,sum(r2 - p) as r3
from d
where drep is not null
group by drep
        ,m
)
,f as(
select d.*
    ,dover.r3
    ,case when d.drep is null
        then d.r2 + isnull(dover.r3 /*- dover.p*/,0) -- abs(isnull(dover.p - (dover.r3 - dover.p),0))
        else d.r2 - (d.r2 - d.p)
        end as ra
from d
    left join dover
        on d.m = dover.m
            and d.d = dover.drep
)
select d,m,p,r,ra
from f
order by m,d
```

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `apply`:

```
select t.*,
       t2.r as imputed_r
from t outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.*
      from t t2
      where t2.m = t.m and
            t2.d >= t.d and t2.r <= t.p
      order by t2.d desc
     ) t2;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=256255a308ba520744a93da7f7143bb1) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my question.  I don't want the `r` count to disappear, but be included in prior rows where the `p` value is large enough to accomodate it.  The totals of `p` and `r` within the table as a whole can't change.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably clean this up a bit but hopefully the verbosity helps you understand what is going.

```
WITH r1 AS (
-- Find what the previous day's p value was so we can compare it with today's
SELECT
    *
    ,LAG(p) OVER (PARTITION BY m ORDER BY d) AS previous_p
FROM
    @t
)
,r2 AS (
-- Compute the change between p valuesin percentage
SELECT
    *
    ,CASE WHEN r1.previous_p > 0 THEN ((r1.p*1.0-r1.previous_p)/r1.previous_p) ELSE 0 END AS p_delta
FROM
    r1
)
,r3 AS (
-- Use the percentage change to check if a machine was "paused"
SELECT
    *
    ,CASE WHEN r2.p_delta > 0.8 OR (r2.previous_p = 0 AND r2.p > 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_new_session -- Adjust 0.8 to whatever percent change makes sense for a new session
FROM
    r2
)
, r4 AS (
-- Put each row for a machine into its corresponding group
SELECT
    *
    ,SUM(r3.is_new_session) OVER (PARTITION BY r3.m ORDER BY r3.d) AS session_group_id
FROM
    r3
)
, r5 AS (
-- Now we can calculate for each group how total p and r leftover are for each day
SELECT
    *
    ,CASE WHEN r4.p-r4.r > 0 AND r4.r > 0 THEN r4.p-r4.r ELSE 0 END AS remaining_p
    ,CASE WHEN r4.r-r4.p > 0 THEN r4.r-r4.p ELSE 0 END AS remaining_r
FROM
    r4
)
, r6 AS (
-- We need to get the accumulating remaining amounts
SELECT
    *
    ,SUM(r5.remaining_p) OVER (PARTITION BY r5.m, r5.session_group_id ORDER BY r5.d ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS total_remaining_p
    ,SUM(r5.remaining_r) OVER (PARTITION BY r5.m, r5.session_group_id ORDER BY r5.d ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS total_remaining_r
FROM
    r5
)
,r7 AS (
-- We then go backwards and subtract accumulating p out of the accumulated r
SELECT
    *
    ,r6.total_remaining_r - r6.total_remaining_p AS adjusted_total_remaining_r
FROM
    r6
)
,r8 AS (
-- Shift everything back one day so the adjusted remaining r can be added to the correct date
SELECT
    *
    ,LEAD(r7.adjusted_total_remaining_r) OVER (PARTITION BY r7.m, r7.session_group_id ORDER BY r7.d) AS next_adjusted_total_remaining_r
FROM
    r7
)
-- Finally, calculate what the corected r amount is for each day
SELECT
    r8.d
   ,r8.m
   ,r8.p
   ,r8.r
    ,CASE WHEN r8.remaining_p > 0 THEN -- If there is any remaing p left where we can put r amounts
        CASE WHEN r8.total_remaining_p > r8.total_remaining_r THEN -- Also check that we have more accumlated left than r
            CASE WHEN r8.next_adjusted_total_remaining_r > 0 THEN r8.r + r8.next_adjusted_total_remaining_r -- If we still have space, add the adjusted amount of what is left
            ELSE r8.r -- If we have run out of extra r, leave it as r
            END
        ELSE r8.p -- For those days that we had to adjust by the max amount possible, r + adjusted_r will just be p
        END
     ELSE r8.r - r8.remaining_r END AS corrected_r -- Remove the extra r where r was greater than p
FROM
    r8
ORDER BY r8.m,r8.d
```

OUTPUT:

```
+------------+---+------+-----+-------------+
|     d      | m |  p   |  r  | corrected_r |
+------------+---+------+-----+-------------+
| 2020-05-27 | 1 |  100 |  10 |          10 |
| 2020-05-28 | 1 |   90 |  10 |          10 |
| 2020-05-29 | 1 |   70 |  10 |          10 |
| 2020-05-30 | 1 |   70 |  10 |          10 |
| 2020-05-31 | 1 |   80 |  10 |          10 |
| 2020-06-01 | 1 |   50 |  10 |          40 |
| 2020-06-02 | 1 |   10 |  10 |          10 |
| 2020-06-03 | 1 |    0 |  10 |           0 |
| 2020-06-04 | 1 |    0 |  10 |           0 |
| 2020-06-05 | 1 |    0 |  10 |           0 |
| 2020-06-06 | 1 |    0 |   0 |           0 |
| 2020-06-07 | 1 |    0 |   0 |           0 |
| 2020-06-08 | 1 |   40 |   0 |           0 |
| 2020-06-09 | 1 |   50 |   0 |           0 |
| 2020-06-10 | 1 |   80 |  10 |          10 |
| 2020-05-27 | 2 | 1100 | 100 |         100 |
| 2020-05-28 | 2 |  190 | 100 |         100 |
| 2020-05-29 | 2 |  170 | 100 |         160 |
| 2020-05-30 | 2 |  170 | 100 |         170 |
| 2020-05-31 | 2 |  180 | 100 |         180 |
| 2020-06-01 | 2 |  150 | 100 |         150 |
| 2020-06-02 | 2 |  110 | 100 |         110 |
| 2020-06-03 | 2 |   10 | 100 |          10 |
| 2020-06-04 | 2 |   10 | 100 |          10 |
| 2020-06-05 | 2 |   10 | 100 |          10 |
| 2020-06-06 | 2 |   10 |   0 |           0 |
| 2020-06-07 | 2 |   10 |   0 |           0 |
| 2020-06-08 | 2 |  140 |   0 |           0 |
| 2020-06-09 | 2 |  150 |   0 |           0 |
| 2020-06-10 | 2 |  180 | 100 |         100 |
+------------+---+------+-----+-------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, but your script falls over with multiple period of excess `r` in a row.  If you are interested I figured this out and posted an answer.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "falls over with multiple period of excess `r` in a row". Your complaint with @gordon-linoff 's answer was that he removed `r` but you do that in your proposed answer too. Mine does not lose any `r`. Is that what the problem is? That I keep all of the `r` values. I've updated my answer to show what the result is based on your provided data.

Comment: It appears that my actual dummy data is an edge case that hasn't shown up in my actual data.  For the issues with your script, add a few rows to `m = 1` inbetween the 4th and 5th `d` that have `p = 0` and `r = 0` and you will see the issue.

Comment: I have edited the script in my answer to account for this.